# Remover os espaços da div com imagem usando Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

Tenho uma div, onde estou salvando o conteúdo usando canvas

```
<div class="container-capa">
    <img src=~/Content/imagemcartaovisita/@Session["NomeCapaCartao"] class="img-responsive" id="capa" alt="" width="589" height="324">
    <label id="caminhosite">@Session["CaminhoSiteUsuario"]</label>
</div>
```

Na função Js eu estou passando o mesmo tamanho da imagem,

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnSaveCartaoCapa").click(function () {
        html2canvas($(".container-capa"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                theCanvas = canvas;
                // document.body.appendChild(canvas);

                // Convert and download as image
                Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas, 589, 324);
                //$(".main-footer").append(canvas);
                // Clean up
                //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

E no css:

```
.container-capa{
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

O Problema e que ao salvar o arquivo a imagem não vem no tamanho correto, vem um espaço em branco, a imagem vem com w280 e h300:
O vermelho seria a imagem e o verde o espaço em branco

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `padding-bottom: 0%;` isso e válido ? PS: *Essa imagem queimou meus olhos*

Comment: @MauroAlexandre, Pelo menos o seu comentário foi engraçado, agora pergunta se padding-bottom existe foi demais kkk

Comment: Eu perguntei pela porcentagem.

Comment: Sim, existe propriedade-css-padding no site do maujor, veja lá!